# Testing AJAX with Rspec: this code works but the spec can't find the route

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rspec

I have this Javascript in a page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function update_price(order_id, quantity) {
    $.ajax({
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(
          'X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
      },
      url: "/carts/" + <%= @cart.id %> + "/update_quantity", #you are missing 's' here is this a typo?
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "order_id" : order_id,
        "quantity" : quantity }
    });
  }
</script>
```

It works just fine for the user. The matching routes look like this:

```
resources :carts, only: %i[update destroy index] do
  member do
    match 'update_quantity', to: 'carts#update_quantity', via: %i[get post]
  end
end
```

My spec looks like this:

```
it 'updates the quantity' do
  post "/cart/#{cart.id}/update_quantity", xhr: true, params: {
    order_id: cart.orders.first.id,
    quantity: 50
  }
  expect(response.status).to eq 200
end
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
   No route matches {:action=>"/cart/2/update_quantity", :controller=>"carts", :order_id=>1, :quantity=>50}
```

In short, it works for the user but I can't get the spec to pass. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Was getting the same error in rails 4 xhr specs. This format works for me:

```
xhr :post, :update_quantity, id: cart.id, order_id: cart.orders.first.id, quantity: 50
```

Looks like you have rails 5 app so try this one:

```
post :update_quantity, xhr: true, params: {
  id: cart.id,
  order_id: cart.orders.first.id,
  quantity: 50
}
```

Note that `xhr` method is deprecated in rails 5 so use option `xhr: true`

Comment: I get `NoMethodError: super: no superclass method `xhr' for ...`. Bit weird?

Comment: @CD-RUM Found that `xhr` is deprecated in rails 5 so `xhr: true` option is the way to go. Updated my answer

Comment: New syntax for Rails 5! Thank you!